# send bool value in soap body as a parameter

Tags: ios, objective-c, soap, soap-client, nsmutableurlrequest

How to send a bool value in soap body in such a way that it should print as false and true rather than 0 or 1 ?

```
"<AllDayEvent>boolean</AllDayEvent>\n"
```

i want the body to print as :

```
"<AllDayEvent>false</AllDayEvent>\n"
```

Thanks & Regards

Answer (score 0):

Boolean lexical forms "1" and "true", "0" and "false" are interchangeable.
From the [Soap spec:](https://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-xmlschema-2-20041028/#boolean)

An instance of a datatype that is defined as boolean:

```
<xsd:element name="AllDayEvent" type="xsd:boolean"/>
```

can have the following legal literals {true, false, 1, 0}.

And the canonical representation for boolean is the set of literals {true, false}.

Answer (score 0):

just create BOOL variable like

```
BOOL isAllDayEvent;
isAllDayEvent=true;
<AllDayEvent>isAllDayEvent</AllDayEvent>
```

try this